# Tor Failed to connected tor network

Tags: help, connection

here's my log i don't know why it wont work. i have even tried using a windows 7 virtual machine. sometimes after hours of trying to getting it to work it does and i don't know what is the issue. my date and time are correct.

```
3/17/2019 21:27:06 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/17/2019 21:27:06 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/17/2019 21:27:06 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/17/2019 21:27:06 PM.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/17/2019 21:27:06 PM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
3/17/2019 21:27:07 PM.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
3/17/2019 21:27:33 PM.500 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host BD6A829255CB08E66FBE7D3748363586E46B3810 at 171.25.193.9:80) 
3/17/2019 21:27:33 PM.500 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
3/17/2019 21:27:33 PM.500 [WARN]  8 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/17/2019 21:27:33 PM.500 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in CLOSED 
3/17/2019 21:27:33 PM.500 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
3/17/2019 21:27:33 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/17/2019 21:27:33 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/17/2019 21:27:33 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/17/2019 21:27:33 PM.600 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Tor is being blocked. SSL is failing, and from my experience, that usually results from the network preventing a connection to the tor network

I'd try using bridges. Currently obsf4 is recommended, and I believe meek-azure works in china

Comment: hey i tried to connect to tor using the obsf4 bridge in the config and it stills is giving me tor failed to establish a tor network connection

Comment: @TORHelp I don't know. Have you tried it on a different network?